# VB.net my.settings not auto icrementing and storing

Tags: vb.net

I have a class that has a list of messages that cycle through based on a given integer stored in the settings. Here is a code snippet that is not working. Am I not incrementing properly for settings?

```
Public Class Messages

Public Sub Punchinmsg()

    Dim msgint As Double = My.Settings.msgint

    If msgint = 0 Then
        MsgBox("You have been punched in... Good thing I don't have arms.")
        msgint = msgint + 1
        My.Settings.Save()
    ElseIf msgint = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Great time for work...")
        msgint = msgint + 1
        My.Settings.Save()
```

My settings are msgint is Double and USER to allow it to be written to at run time.

Comment: what is the current value?

Comment: the default value in settings is 0 the goal it it to increment to 10 then reset to 0

Comment: you need to assign your updated values back to your my.settings before saving your settings file.  For example add my.settting.msgint = msgint  before the my.settings.save

Comment: ahhh thanks that makes sense i do that in the other areas of the app. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it takes a new set of eyes to find something right in from of you

Comment: BTW, there is nothing auto increment about `msgint = msgint + 1`

Comment: Why is it not? It is auto incrementing now I just had to commit the new value back to the setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a local variable, but not the setting that has the same name. Before calling My.Settings.Save, you must set the setting. Example...

```
msgint = msgint + 1 'This only updates the local variable.
My.Settings.msgint = msgint 'Assigns a new value to the setting named msgint.
My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: Rob commented that almost immediately and I commented back thank. I know I thought you were pointing out something else.